# Problem with mutableStateFlow retrofit and jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2

I use MutableStateFlow and get data from server i need username text on my screen
In onCreate() i get profile method from viewModel and in log.d my data is correct, but textUserName not update in Composables if i use method 1 , and updated if i use method 2, but i need load data only once and use this in all app.

ViewModel class :

```
private val _getProfileResponseStateFlow: MutableStateFlow<ProfileResponse> =
        MutableStateFlow(ProfileResponse())
    val getProfileResponseStateFlow = _getProfileResponseStateFlow.asStateFlow()

fun getProfile() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = getProfileUseCase.execute(
                sharedPreferences.getAccessToken()?.toBearer().toString()
            )

            if (result.isSuccessful) {
                isSuccessGetProfile.value = true
                _getProfileResponseStateFlow.value = result.body()!!
            }
        }
    }
```

Composable text

```
@Composable
fun UserName(
    modifier: Modifier,
    fontSize: TextUnit
) {

    val viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()

  

    val profileDataState by viewModel.getProfileResponseStateFlow.collectAsState()


    Text(
        text = profileDataState.name.toString(),
        modifier = modifier,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = fontSize,
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
    )
}
```

i try this and this work, but i want load data only once

```
 LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) { // i need without this, i want get data only once 
    viewModel.getProfile()
}
```

Comment: You can call ```viewModel.getProfile()``` in init block of viewmodel.

Comment: I call viewModel.getProfile() from mainActivity, onCreate() or is this bad solution ?
But i get null value on text(start value)

Comment: ViewModel.getProfile() will invoke again if the activity is recreated(Screen Rotate) but if you call it in the init block of ViewModel then it will not. It's up to you

Comment: Thanks. but I still don’t understand why I still get null instead of the username value, although I call getProfile() in activity, but if I call it from Composable it works

Comment: Make sure that profileDataState is updated after API call.

Comment: init in viewModel solved the problem, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `getProfile()` function inside `init()` method in your viewmodel class. ViewModel will have not effect when Recomposition occur

```
class Profile: ViewModel() {
   init(){
    getProfile()
   }
}
```